# Difference between blow up and blow up over

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

I saw the meaning of blow up which is explode or anger. but could not find any reference related to blow up over.

Sentence - This was an embarrassing moment for company that blew up over social media. They spent the next few weeks doing damage control and addressing their mistake with thousands of people

Answer (score 1):

"Blow up" is a phrasal verb,  "over social media" is a prepositional phrase.  "Blow up over" isn't a thing

The meaning of "blow up" is related to explode, but figuratively. It means "become much worse very quickly" and "over social media" tell you how, or where, that occurred.

There was an "embarrassing moment". This became much worse very quickly because it was shared by people, over social media.

Comment: For clarity, "blow up over" isn't a thing

Comment: "Blow up over" is of course a thing. In the sense used in the OP's context it means the *means of* blowing up: blow up **over text**, over **social media**, etc. But it could also mean the *reason for* blowing up: blow up **over the state of the kitchen** for example.

Comment: @James K, I saw the dictionary, everywhere it is mentioned about sudden anger. if you don't mind, if you would please share the info source?